# save data in editable dynamic html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have created editable dynamic html table, on double click over a text the user is able to change it but the change is temporary, i wish to save it in database also.

My code for table is ([@jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/rzmnqfqa/))

html table

```
<table class="editableTable table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> A </th>
        <th> B </th>
        <th> C </th>
        <th> D </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php
    $sql=" SELECT * from orderid";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {?> <tr>
                        <td> <? echo $row['a']; ?> </td>
                        <td> <? echo $row['b']; ?> </td>
                        <td> <? echo $row['c']; ?> </td>
                        <td> <? echo $row['d']; ?> </td>
                    </tr>   
                <?}
        }?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

script code

```
 $(function () 
        { 
            $("td").dblclick(function () 
                { 
                    var OriginalContent = $(this).text(); 
                    $(this).addClass("cellEditing"); 
                    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />"); 
                    $(this).children().first().focus(); 
                    $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) 
                        {
                            if (e.which == 13)
                                {   
                                    var newContent = $(this).val(); 
                                    $(this).parent().text(newContent); 
                                    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing"); 
                                } 
                        }); 
                    $(this).children().first().blur(function()
                        {
                            $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent); 
                            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing"); 
                        }); 
                }); 
        });
```

code i wish to use to edit the entry is

```
$sql1="UPDATE tablename set A='".$a."', B= '".$b."', C= '".$c."', D= '".$d."' WHERE id='".$id."' ";
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
    {
        die('Error:' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
```

table view

```
id  A  B  C  D
1   a  b  c  d
```

Can anyone please tell me how i can save the new entry in database

Comment: you can call a api to save a data in database

Comment: you can use ajax then save the data in your database on click event

Comment: @Rohit Azad can u please tell me how to do so

Comment: Add a save button and on click fire a ajax post request to your server on a php page with the update code.

Comment: @lyra now mr. Thanasis Grammatopoulos do this

Comment: @Thanasis Grammatopoulos adding a save button, then won't the user have to click over it every time to make a new entry.. is there an option to save it directly

Comment: @Pekka i tried ajax but i am not able to use it properly

Comment: If you do that on keypress that will do more saving clicking button is better way

Comment: You can fire your ajax after you removeClass("cellEditing") , so any change will be sent to the server.

Comment: @Thanasis Grammatopoulos i tried to doing so but didn't got the result, can u also please tell me how to  distinguish which column has been edited and in which row?

Comment: You have more problems than you think. If you want only to save the change you can use $(this).data('id') and $(this).data('name') to get this info if you use <td data-id="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" data-name="a"> <? echo $row['a']; ?> </td> but you have to parse everything serverside so you do not have sql injection problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working (at the client) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmr2j4uc/1/) example .

I fix you a remove class problem, $(this) was the input and by doing $(this).parent().text("") then $(this) does not exist to get his parent again.

So you can print your table like this

```
<tr data-id="1"><!-- Include here the row id -->
    <td data-name="a"> a1 </td><!-- Include each cell's name -->
    <td data-name="b"> b1 </td>
    <td data-name="c"> c1 </td>
    <td data-name="d"> d1 </td>
</tr>
```

I added you a save function

```
    var saveChanges = function(cell){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'save_changes.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: getData(cell),
            success: function (json){
                if(json.error){
                    console.log('Error : '+json.error);
                }else{
                    console.log('Data saved.');
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('Can not connect to the server.');
            }
        });
    }
```

And a get data function

```
var getData = function(cell){
    var data = {
        "id" : $.trim(cell.parent().data('id')), // Get row id
        "name" : $.trim(cell.data('name')), // Get the tuple name
        "value" : $.trim(cell.html()) // Get new value
    };
    return data;
}
```

On the server you need a php file to save the data, the code should be something like

```
    // Server Code
    // file "save_changes.php"

    // SQL injection protect
    // http://www.bitrepository.com/sanitize-data-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html
    function sanitize($data){
        // remove whitespaces (not a must though)
        $data = trim($data);

        // apply stripslashes if magic_quotes_gpc is enabled
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $data = stripslashes($data);
        }

        // a mySQL connection is required before using this function
        $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

        return $data;
    }

    if(isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["value"])){
        $id = sanitize($_POST["id"]);
        $name = sanitize($_POST["name"]);
        $value = sanitize($_POST["value"]);
        // Save Data
            // Here you save your data
            $sql1="UPDATE tablename set '".$name."'='".$value."' WHERE id='".$id."' ";
            if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)){
                echo '{"error":"'.mysqli_error($con).'"}';
            } else {
                // Report ok
                echo '{"status":"success"}';
            }
    } else {
        echo '{"error":"missing data"}';
    }
```

Be carefull with the spaces, i added some $.trim() to remove them.
If new content is the same with the old, no change will be send to the server, you may want to disable it.

```js
$(function() {
  var getData = function(cell) {
    var data = {
      "id": $.trim(cell.parent().data('id')),
      "name": $.trim(cell.data('name')),
      "value": $.trim(cell.html())
    };
    return data;
  }
  var saveChanges = function(cell) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'save_changes.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: getData(cell),
      success: function(json) {
        if (json.error) {
          console.log('Error : ' + json.error);
        } else {
          console.log('Data saved.');
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('Can not connect to the server.');
      }
    });
    /*
        // Server Code
        // file "save_changes.php"
        
        // SQL injection protect
        // http://www.bitrepository.com/sanitize-data-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html
        function sanitize($data){
            // remove whitespaces (not a must though)
            $data = trim($data);

            // apply stripslashes if magic_quotes_gpc is enabled
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
                $data = stripslashes($data);
            }

            // a mySQL connection is required before using this function
            $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

            return $data;
        }

        if(isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["value"])){
            $id = sanitize($_POST["id"]);
            $name = sanitize($_POST["name"]);
            $value = sanitize($_POST["value"]);
            // Save Data
                // Here you save your data
                $sql1="UPDATE tablename set '".$name."'='".$value."' WHERE id='".$id."' ";
                if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql1)){
                    echo '{"error":"'.mysqli_error($con).'"}';
                } else {
                    // Report ok
                    echo '{"status":"success"}';
                }
        } else {
            echo '{"error":"missing data"}';
        }
    */
  }

  $("#myData td").dblclick(function() {
    var OriginalContent = $.trim($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
    $(this).children().first().focus();
    $(this).children().first().keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        var newContent = $(this).val();
        var cell = $(this).parent();
        cell.text(newContent);
        cell.removeClass("cellEditing");
        if ($.trim(newContent) != OriginalContent)
          saveChanges(cell);
      }
    });
    $(this).children().first().blur(function() {
      var cell = $(this).parent();
      cell.text(OriginalContent);
      cell.removeClass("cellEditing");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.editableTable {
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 100%
}
.editableTable td {
  border: solid 1px;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing {
  padding: 0;
}
.editableTable .cellEditing input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 253, 210);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myData" class="editableTable table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-id="1">
      <!-- Include here the row id -->
      <td data-name="a">a1</td>
      <!-- Include each cell's name -->
      <td data-name="b">b1</td>
      <td data-name="c">c1</td>
      <td data-name="d">d1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="2">
      <!-- Include here the row id -->
      <td data-name="a">a2</td>
      <!-- Include each cell's name -->
      <td data-name="b">b2</td>
      <td data-name="c">c2</td>
      <td data-name="d">d2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you save the data if the user is allowed to add/remove rows and columns to the table??

Comment: Since all the changes for now where only an "UPDATE" query, it is logical that in order to add a row, we would have to ask the server to create an "INSERT" and to delete a row to ask for a "DELETE". These should be different handlers and modify the table after the server responded. Something like, `click add row button` > `ajax make INSERT` > `server responds with the id` > `create row on the table and apply click handlers`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#save").click(function () {
    var dataA='Data in A td';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your php page where you do the insert',
        dataType: "json",//response from php page
        data: {
            dataA: dataA//data you will save in database
            },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
           alert("Error");
        }


    });
});
```

You can do it like this. Just change the url of the php page then you can also change the dataType into what ever you want the php page to respond example are text and html and more

Comment: i tried your code but nothing happened.. one moret hing i would like to ask, in your code how will i distinguish which column has been edited and in which row??

Comment: You have to change the `url part` into the php page where you do the database transactions.as suggested above you can run the ajax function after you have `remove the class cellEditing`. So what you would know which row is being edited.What do you mean by nothing happened.If you copy and paste it nothing will happened you need to change the url and do all the database transcation from there on

Comment: i had changed the url link to page where i had the edit code that i have given in my post, and placed the code after  $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");  by nothing happened i meant that i didnt got any response in console and no alert box appeared